# Eclipse C macro automatic formatting

Tags: c, eclipse, macros, code-formatting, eclipse-cdt

I'm having a problem with using the automatic formatting in Eclipse CDT. For the most part it works great but it seems to insist on putting the semicolons after macro calls on a separate line.

Is this a bug or did I mischeck a combination of formatting settings which lead to this?

Comment: Which Eclipse version are you referring to and which formatter did you set up?  Also you might give an example?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because outdate. The issue had been fixed in recent Eclipse releases.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem has (reportedly) been fixed in later versions of Eclipse CDT and so is no longer relevant (and the sensible advice is "if you encounter it, upgrade").

Comment: Any idea in what version of Eclipse CDT? I am using Kinetis Design Studio (Eclipse Based) with Eclipse CDT version 8.6.0.201502131403 and the issue is still present.

Comment: probably  Helios /3.6 with whatever was the newest CDT at the time(May 2011)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed in later versions of Eclipse CDT. Just try to download later version of Eclipse.

Comment: are you sure? Is there a bug number/link? Someone in the comments still seems to be experiencing this.