# Eclipse CDT macro automatic formatting

Tags: c, eclipse, macros, eclipse-cdt, code-formatting

I am using TrueSTUDIO 9.1.0 and also tested this within fresh Eclipse IDE for C/C++ developers version: 2018-09 (4.9.0).

Automatic code formatter seems to be putting semicolon after a macro call on a new line.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download Eclipse IDE for C/C++ developers version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) for Windows 32bit.
2. Create new empty C project
3. Create .c file with code:

   `#define testmacro() do {printf("test");} while (0)`

   `void main(void) {
       testmacro();
   }`
4. Format the whole file by pressing Ctrl+Shift+F
5. Get:

   `#define testmacro() do {printf("test");} while (0)

   void main(void) {
       testmacro()
       ;
   }`

It was discussed and dismissed in this question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881284/eclipse-c-macro-automatic-formatting)) for the reason that it was fixed.

Am I doing something wrong or did the error come back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong, the CDT built-in formatter is just buggy and unmaintained. There are dozens of open bugs about its behaviour. In this case, it looks like [bug 475349](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475349).

I would recommend using a plugin that wraps a modern, maintained formatter like `clang-format`, such as [CppStyle](http://www.cppstyle.com/).

Comment: I actually managed to properly install CppStyle for TrueStudio and it is working. Thanks.